# How to make orientation response faster in ipad?

Tags: optimization, ipad

I have ipad application which has 3 tableviews with holds data like label,image,property lists etc, as while performing orientation it has some overlapping,slow response compared to native apps,

I have tried some methods like willRotateToInterfaceOrientation etc,

is that any thing that make sense to make orientation faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it is a set speed/time. I would believe Apple has set it so that there is a uniform feeling throughout apps. As with pretty much everything, I'm sure there is a way to do it, but I am not sure if Apple approves it for App Store apps, or if it is just a hidden detail.

Comment: is that any Timer functions we can set to make the response or to reduce overlap issues while orientation?

Comment: As far as rotating the screen, you build your application for both orientations if you will allow rotating, and as far as I know, the timer and method for transitioning are there to use but not very accessible besides implementation. The slowness may have to do with what the iPad is attempting to rotate, some inefficiency in your code, or maybe a mixture of the both (no offense). I would not worry too much about rotation speed/smoothness compared to native apps. Apple has not given us everything they had to work with while building our own apps.